# xpath expression for xml response, need condition

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlmapper

I have an xml like below ..

```
    <parent>
      <child>
        <f1>abh</f1>
        <f2>jb</f2>
      </child>
      <child>
        <f1>abh2</f1>
        <f2>jb2</f2>
      </child>
    </parent>
```

How do i get the f1 of child which has f2's value as jb2 using xpath expression?

Answer (score 2):

**XPath**

```
/parent/child[f2="jb2"]/f1
```